# MySQL SELECT all unique list of dates (right format)

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to select and extract dates formatted as dates from MySQL with Python. Furthermore, I don't want all values on the date column (there are thousands of rows), but rather just a dedup list from that column so I can then use them as variables for other piece of the code. Something like: `2021/04/21, 2021/04/22, etc.`

**code**

```js
mycursor.execute("SELECT DATE(date) FROM db_cryptoprice")
test = mycursor.fetchall()
print(test)
```

**results**

```
.date(2021, 4, 21),), (datetime.date(2021, 4, 21),), (datetime.date(2021, 4, 21),), (datetime.date(2021, 4, 21),), (datetime.date(2021, 4, 21),), (datetime.date(2021, 4, 21),), (datetime.date(2021, 4, 21),), (datetime.date(2021, 4, 21),), (datetime.date(2021, 4, 21),), (datetime.date(2021, 4, 21),), (datetime.date(2021, 4, 21),), (datetime.date(2021, 4, 21),), (datetime.date(2021, 4, 21),), (datetime.date(2021, 4, 21),), (datetime.date(2021, 4, 21),), (datetime.date(2021, 4, 21),), (datetime.date(2021, 4, 21),), (datetime.date(2021, 4, 21),), (datetime.date(2021, 4, 21),), (datetime.date(2021, 4, 21),), (datetime.date(2021, 4, 21),), (datetime.date(2021, 4, 21),), (datetime.date(2021, 4, 21),)]
```

If I `list(dic.fromkeys(test))` it returns the following.

**code**

```js
mycursor.execute("SELECT DATE(date) FROM db_cryptoprice")
test = mycursor.fetchall()
getdate= list(dict.fromkeys(test))

print(getdate)
```

**results** - # this is the closest I've got to what I want, but I'm not sure if we can make a date out of this list/tuple.

```
[(datetime.date(2021, 4, 18),), (datetime.date(2021, 4, 19),), (datetime.date(2021, 4, 20),), (datetime.date(2021, 4, 21),)]
```

Comment: If you want to get the first date, you would run something like: `print(getdate[0][0])`. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: You can format the first date by running `print(getdate[0][0].strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))`

Comment: Oh man... that's it! that was so simple! I'm very new with all the terminology and I'm self-taught on all of this.

Comment: Cool, that's fabulous, just what I needed. Please feel free to add this as an answer and I'll accept it right away ;)